# jquery prevent form submitting for ajax request?

Tags: jquery

**REFINED QUESTION**

My JS code for live form and live form submit...

```
$('#addHotlink').click(function() {

$('body').after('<div id="lightBox" style="height: ' + htmlHeight + 'px;"><div><h3>Choose a name for your hotlink:<img id="lightBoxClose" src="http://www.example.com/images/closedAccordion.png" height="17" width="17" alt="" title="Close this box" /></h3><form id="addHotlinkForm" action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off"><input id="hotlinkName" type="text" maxlength="15" /><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Add Hotlink" /></form></div></div>');
$('#lightBox').hide().fadeIn('fast');
return false;
});

$('#addHotlinkForm').live('submit', function(event) {

event.preventDefault();
var hotlinkName = $('#hotlinkName').val();
if (hotlinkName.length > 0) {

    $.ajax({data: {hotlinkName: hotlinkName, hotlinkURL: pageURL},
                    error: function() {

                            alert('Error');
                    },
                success: function() {

            alert('Yay');
        }
    });
}
```

});

My ajax.php...

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['hotlinkName']) && isset($_REQUEST['hotlinkURL'])) {

$q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO hotlinks (id, hotlinkName, hotlinkURL) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$q -> execute(array($_SESSION['id'], $_REQUEST['hotlinkName'], $_REQUEST['hotlinkURL'])); 
}
```

I have my ajax settings set up like so before the ajax call...

```
$.ajaxSetup({

type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax',
dataType: 'json'
});
```

The ajax call doesn't succeed or get an error! In chrome console I get this:

**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation**

Comment: Just tried event.preventDefault to, it doesn't work? Does it matter that it is a live DOM element?

Comment: Are you monitoring the script in a console and seeing what happens? Are there any errors?

Comment: I only have firebug lite for chrome and don't know how to use it yet lol

Comment: Chrome has a native console; do `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open it.

Comment: You do seem to be having some variable naming conflicts.  Also, I don't usually use `$.ajax()`, but doesn't it require a url?

Comment: You shouldn't have trouble retrieving the value of an input field when using a `live()` function.  Unless, of course, you're not retrieving the value properly in the first place.  Again, can you post the HTML?

Comment: Yes going to update full question with everything now.

Comment: I have ajax settings jbrookover

Answer (score 1):

Try using `preventDefault()`:

```
$('#addHotlinkForm').live('submit', function(event) { // add 'event' here

var hotlinkName = $('#hotlinkName').val();
if (hotlinkName.length == 0) {

    return false;
}
else {

    $.ajax({data: {hotlinkName: hotlinkName, hotlinkURL: pageURL},
                success: function(response) {

            alert('Yay!');
        }   
    });
}
event.preventDefault(); // and add in this line
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`live()` methods are attached to a parent component, high up in the DOM hierarchy.  Your default behavior is triggered long before the `live()` function is even reached because the `live()` is triggered after a long bubble up process.

The only real solution is to ensure that the default behavior is a no-op.  You can do this by changing your form's href to `javascript:void(0);`.

**Update**

Your code triggers the alert at this JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/vD2pz/  The only other thing I can think of is that your `addHotLink` creates invalid code by repeatedly creating forms with duplicate ID fields, which is invalid.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for your form?  Another option would be to use `<form href='javascript:jquerySubmitHandler(this)'>`